# Unable to approve "FB comments"

Tags: facebook, comments

I have tried using many plugins for FB Comments in WP. But all these plugins are cluttered and rersults in conflicts and many bugs. So I have decided to insert fb comments manually into my website and I have did that too. The problem now is I am not getting new comments into my moderation queue though I have set "Allow comments after my approval" in Moderation settings of my FB app. Even through my website I am getting only " Hide, Ban, Boost comments".  Approve is not there. Have I missed something to be done while inserting fb comments?

Answer (score 0):

If you specified the fb:appId and fb:admins correctly per the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ and https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490)

then go to 
`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments`.